# How to evaluate double integral: $\iint \frac{y}{x} \, dx \, dy$ if it is in the first quadrant and is bounded by: $y=0$, $y=x$, and $x^2 + 4y^2 = 4$

Tags: integration, analysis, functions

I want to evaluate this double integral:

$$
\iint \frac{y}{x} \, dx \, dy \quad
$$

which is bounded by functions:

$$
y = 0 \quad
$$
$$
y = x \quad
$$
$$
x^2 + 4y^2 = 4 \quad
$$

And is in the first quadrant. The thing is that I don't quite get how to determine if the domain is x-simple, y-simple, or both exactly. I can determine it in easy graphs, but most of the time I'm stuck in there. After determining it, which variable should I take as constant and how should I place upper and lower bounds in the integral? These are the main things that stuck me on this problem. I would love any kind of help here and thank you in advance.

We say that the domain **D** in the **xy**-plane is **y-simple** if it is bounded by two vertical lines **x = a** and **x = b** and two continuous graphs **y = c(x)** and **y = d(x)** between these lines. Lines parallel to the y-axis intersect a y-simple domain in an interval (possibly a single point) if at all. Similarly, **D** is **x-simple** if it is bounded by horizontal lines **y = c** and **y = d** and two continuous graphs **x = a(y)** and **x = b(y)** between these lines. Some of the domains are both **x-simple** and **y-simple**, for example, rectangles, triangles, and disks.

[image]

Comment: What is an $x$-simple function? I might not be the only reader unfamiliar with that terminology?

Comment: Regions, not functions, are $x$- or $y$-simple.

Comment: You have one constant function in $y$ so this might be good as one side of the outer bound, and it looks like $y=1$ may be the other side of that.  But that would make two piecewise integrals for two different outer bounds on $x$, so perhaps switching those outer bounds to being in $x$ and making $y$ be the inner bound would be better.

Comment: Introduce a new variable $x' = x/2$, so that the ellipse becomes a circle.  Then transform the integral into polar coordinates.

Comment: Thank you all for the corrections and suggestions. I have edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at the domain
$$\Omega=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\colon 0\leq y\leq x,\, x^2+4y^2\leq4\}$$
and notice that $$x^2+4y^2\leq4\iff \frac{x^2}{2^2}+y^2\leq 1$$
[image: img]
In red we have $\Omega$, in green the ellipse described by $x^2+4y^2\leq4$ and in blu we have $y=x$.
In order to compute
$$\iint_{\Omega} \frac{y}{x} \, dx \, dy$$
we use the "elliptic change of variable" which are a variation of the polar coordinates:
$$\begin{cases}
x=x_0+a\rho\cos(\theta)\\
y=y_0+b\rho\sin(\theta)
\end{cases}
$$
where $\rho\geq 0, \theta\in [0,2\pi]$ and $(x_0,y_0)$ is the center of the ellipse and $a, b$ are the two parameters that describe the ellipse. In our case,
$$(x_0,y_0)=(0,0)$$
$$a=2, b=1$$
so we get
$$\begin{cases}
x=2\rho\cos(\theta)\\
y=\rho\sin(\theta)
\end{cases}
$$
so we have that
\begin{align}
0\leq y\leq x &\iff 0\leq \rho\sin(\theta)\leq 2\rho\cos(\theta)\\ 
&\iff 0\leq \tan(\theta)\leq 2 \\
&\iff 0\leq \theta\leq\arctan(2)
\end{align}
and, substituting into the ellipse inequality, we deduce that $0\leq\rho\leq 1$. One can show (it's a pretty simple exercise) that the Jacobian of the trasformation is given by
$$J=ab\rho\Rightarrow J=2\rho$$
So the integral reads as following:
\begin{align}
\iint_{\Omega} \frac{y}{x} \, dx \, dy
&=\int_0^1\int_0^{\arctan(2)}\frac{\rho\sin(\theta)}{2\rho\cos(\theta)}2\rho\,d\theta\,d\rho\\
&=\int_0^1\rho\,d\rho\,\int_0^{\arctan(2)}\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)}\,d\theta\\
&=\left(\frac{\rho^2}{2}\right|_{0}^{1}\bigg(-\ln(\cos(\theta))\bigg|_{0}^{\arctan(2)}=-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\cos(\arctan(2))\right)
\end{align}
Now, since
$$\cos(\arctan(x))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$
$$\iint_{\Omega} \frac{y}{x} \, dx \, dy = -\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right)=\frac{1}{4}\ln(5).$$

Comment: thank you so much.

Comment: @Nebula You are welcome :)

Comment: I have done some calculations and get the answer and I think you have miscalculation somewhere. I will write the answer tomorrow which I have evaluated. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Nebula Now it should be correct.

Comment: Your $0\leq\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{4}$ is not right, it should be $0\leq\theta\leq\arctan2$, because  $$y=x\iff2\rho\cos(\theta)=\rho\sin(\theta)\iff\tan(\theta)=2.$$                    
 And $$\iint_{\Omega} \frac{y}{x} \, dx \, dy=\frac{\ln5}{4}.$$

Comment: @Riemann Damn, you are right, my bad.

Comment: Now the answer has been edited and should be right, thank to @Riemann for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

Divide the domain $D$ into two subdomains:
$$D_1:0\leq x\leq\frac{2}{\sqrt 5},0\leq y\leq x;\qquad
D_2:\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}\leq x\leq2,0\leq y\leq\frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}{2},$$
then
\begin{align*}
\iint_{D} \frac{y}{x} \, dx\, dy
&=\iint_{D_1} \frac{y}{x} \, dx \, dy
+\iint_{D_2} \frac{y}{x} \, dx \, dy\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}}\, dx\int_{0}^{x}\frac{y}{x}\, dy
+\int_{\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}}^{2}\, dx\int_{0}^{\frac{\sqrt{4-x^2}}{2}}\frac{y}{x}\, dy\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}}\frac{x}{2}\, dx+\int_{\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}}^{2}\frac{4-x^2}{8x}\, dx\\
&=\frac{x^2}{4}\bigg|_{0}^{\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}}+\left(\frac12\ln x-\frac{x^2}{16}\right)\bigg|_{\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}}^{2}\\
&=\frac{1}{5}+\left[\frac12(\ln2-\ln\frac{2}{\sqrt5})-\frac{1}{16}(4-4/5)\right]\\
&=\frac{\ln5}{4}.
\end{align*}

**Also** the domain $D$ can be described
$$D:0\leq y\leq\frac{2}{\sqrt 5},y\leq x\leq2\sqrt{1-y^2},$$
and then
$$\iint_{D} \frac{y}{x} \, dx\, dy
=\int_{0}^{\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}}\, dy\int_{y}^{2\sqrt{1-y^2}}\frac{y}{x}\, dx=\cdots=\frac{\ln5}{4}.$$